# Why is the parameter needed in funtion

Tags: javascript, xml, parameters

I am trying to learn and understand XML. I found this example on W3schools.
There is a part where the function gets the parameter xml.
I dont understand why it needs this parameter is there someone who can explain this to me?

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: Because that's the response the function is working with. Inside that response is the XML itself.

Comment: So the parameter is filled before it gets to the function? and by what is it filled?

Comment: myFunction.call(this) does also work (replace xml with this). It has nothing todo with xml, its rather js basics...

Comment: The `onreadystatechange` handler gets the response and calls `myFunction` with it. You might want to take a step back: there's a big difference between "learning XML" and "learning JavaScript". The stuff we're talking about now has nothing to do with XML--it's JavaScript and its asynchronous programming model.

Comment: thx for the help @DaveNewton ! appreciate it

Comment: @jonas what you said doesn`t work! you can try at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2

Comment: my fault @jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
console.log(this);
     } 
};
```

The *this* keyword refers to the context a certain function is running in. It might by an Object, usually its Window.
Examples

```
function hi(){
  alert(this);//window
}
function person(){
this.hi=hi;
}
Mark=new Person();
Mark.hi();//mark
```

In your example, this is the xml object. You can access this.responseXML for example.
But js this doesnt behave like in other languages:

```
function inyourxmlcallback(){
  alert(this);//xml
  hi();//window
 }
```

Function calls dont automatically bind this to the called functions. You need to do it manually:

```
hi.call(this);//xml object
```

W3 schools simply passes the context as a variable, to use it later.
Example:

```
var test=this;
alert(test);//window
```